# Azure Functions fails to find API key with "Unable to resolve value for property 'SendGridAttribute.ApiKey'."

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

As per the documentation [How to use SendGrid in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-sendgrid), we need to create an entry for the SendGrid API key. The documentation contains a screenshot of a panel called "Application settings" that appears to not exist anywhere (perhaps the documentation isn't being kept up to date with the UI...).

I have however been able to create keys in 3 other places that seem appropriate (again, the UI seems pretty poor and I'm having to guess here).

Please can someone advise on this?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Platform Features` -> `Application Settings`

[image]

then add your setting to `App settings`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will want to click on the "Platform features" link/tab at the top.  Another panel will emerge, then click the "Application settings" link under General Settings.  If you scroll down the page, you will arrive at the App settings section.